# Need a reference for a hadith about staying at the grave after burial

Tags: dua, death, parents, funeral

I recently came across a quote on FB that was claimed as being a hadith. The summary of the quote was that after the janazah and burial of one's deceased parent, one should stay at their grave, reciting surahs and duas for them for such an amount of time that is equivalent to the time it takes a person to slaughter a camel, skin it and to cut and distribute its meat. Otherwise, the deceased feels as if they have been set adrift in the sea without any support.
I wanted to confirm whether this is actually a hadith or not, before forwarding it to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [hadith in Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/228) wherein 'Amr bin Al-'As says to his son:

> When you bury me, fill my grave well with earth, then stand around it for the time within which a camel is slaughtered and its meat is distributed so that I may enjoy your intimacy and (in your company) ascertain what answer I can give to the messengers (angels) of Allah.

However, this single narration doesn't indicate that this is a blessed act or something ordained by the prophet, simply a personal request by 'Amr bin Al-'As himself.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply brother. I too have come across it in Sahih Muslim but since it wasn't a quote of the Prophet (PBUH), I thought I should ask here. My thinking was that only quotes of the Holy Prophet are considered as hadith.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is only single narration of the COMPANION OF THE HOLY PROPHET .This was his personal wish and not saying of the Holy PROPHET .IT SAYS

'Amr bin Al-'as (May Allah be pleased with him) used to say:
"When you have buried me, keep standing near my grave till (for the time it takes to) a camel is slaughtered and its meat is distributed, so that I may feel your nearness and know what to reply to the angels sent by my Rubb."

[Muslim].

وعن عمرو بن العاص رضي الله عنه قال‏:‏ إذا دفنتمونى، فأقيموا حول قبري قدر ما تنحر جذور، ويقسم لحمها حت أستأنس بكم، وأعلم ماذا أراجع به رسل ربي‏"‏ ‏(‏‏(‏رواه مسلم‏.‏ وقد سبق بطوله‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏ وقال الشافعي رحمه الله‏:‏ ويستحب أن يقرأ عنده شيء من القرآن، وإن ختموا القرآن عنده كان حسناً‏.‏
وقال الشافعي رحمه الله‏:‏ ويستحب أن يقرأ عنده شيء من القرآن، وإن ختموا القرآن عنده كان حسناً‏.‏

RIAYDH SALHEEN

Book 7, Hadith 53

Answer (score 1):

The hadith of 'Amr ibn Al-'Aas in Sahih Muslim is mawqoof, however it is presumable that he was acting on the teachings of the Prophet ﷺ rather than on his personal wishes. A hadith from the Prophet ﷺ which supports the general meaning of it includes:

> #### عن عثمان بن عفان، قال: كان النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم، إذا فرغ من دفن الميت وقف عليه، فقال: استغفروا لأخيكم، وسلوا له بالتثبيت، فإنه الآن يسأل
>
> Narrated Uthman ibn Affan:
>
> Whenever the Prophet (ﷺ) became free from burying the dead, he used to stay at him (i.e. his grave) and say: Seek forgiveness for your brother, and beg steadfastness for him, for he will be questioned now
>
> <sup>— [Sunan Abi Dawud , كتاب الجنائز](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/21/133)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a reference for a hadith about staying in the grave after burial?
In her will, Hazrat Zahra (PBUH) said to the Commander of the Faithful (PBUH): Do not go after you have buried me; Sit down and read the Quran. The corpse needs to read the Qur'an; Because the dead in such a situation need more than anything to have intercourse with the living.

Ref: https://rasanews.ir/fa/news/222566/%D8%A2%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%AF%D9%81%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%88-%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84-%D9%BE%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%A2%D9%86